# Suitable Resolution for my screen is not showing!

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution

I'm very new to ubuntu. Yesterday I had installed **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.** All the installation gone very successful. After that I booted it up. And I gone to the settings and in display settings the screen resolution for my monitor is not showing.

The screen resolution for my monitor is `1366 x 768`. I am using `intel i3 10100` processor and not using any other graphics cards other than `intel uhd graphics 630`. Somebody please help me. Is this any problem with graphics driver or something else? I don't know what the issue!

**Please help me to fix this!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a *very* new computer, which means you'll need to install the 20.10 release of Ubuntu. Fortunately it's pretty easy:

1. Open the "Software & Updates" application
2. Go to the "Updates" tab
3. Find the section titled "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version"
4. Change "For long-term support versions" to “For any new version” (as seen in the image below)
5. If asked for your password, type it in
6. Click "Close"

[image: Software and Updates]

From there, you can check for updates and the system will prompt you to upgrade to 20.10, which has the necessary drivers to get the most out of your new computer.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Is there is any another way to fix this??

Comment: *Technically*, yes. You can grab a more recent kernel from upstream and custom compile something that is specific for your machine. However, your very first sentence in the question was "I'm very new to Ubuntu", so providing a bunch of complicated commands in a terminal seems like a very bad idea. Updating to the 20.10 interim release will most likely resolve your issue, and this can be done completely within the GUI, making it simpler and accessible.

Comment: Tell me the commands that will much helpful for me!!!

Comment: [This article](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/) will walk you through two methods of updating your kernel manually. This is a great deal more work than simply upgrading to 20.10. That said, 十人十色 